# Datagrid columns and row cursor

Tags: c#, datagrid

When the divider length is increased in the datagrid for rows and columns , the resize cursor appears on only one side . How to make the cursor resizable on the entire divider for rows and columns ?

Here data grid is used for the GUI(for touch screen panel), where the user can resize rows and columns ..

Comment: can you please share your design...or share your design on Fiddle..

Comment: @MayankPathak: Its a grid(to display a rectangle) with 3 rows and 3 columns, are re-sizable with divider length 15.

Comment: well, you need to share your design's code...